# manipulating pandas dataframe - conditional

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID    Date         Event_Type
1     01/01/2019   A
1     01/01/2019   B
2     02/01/2019   A
3     02/01/2019   A
```

I want to be left with:

```
ID    Date
1     01/01/2019
2     02/01/2019
3     02/01/2019
```

Where my condition is:
If the `ID` is the same AND the `dates` are within 2 days of each other then drop one of the rows.
If however the dates are more than 2 days apart then keep both rows.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I couldn't think of the logic of how to do this. @jezreal solved it for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need first convert values to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then get [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and get first values per groups by `isnull()` chained with comparing if next values are higher like timedelta treshold:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

s =  df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff()
df = df[(s.isnull() | (s > pd.Timedelta(2, 'd')))]
print (df)
   ID       Date Event_Type
0   1 2019-01-01          A
2   2 2019-02-01          A
3   3 2019-02-01          A
```

Check solution with another data:

```
print (df)
   ID        Date Event_Type
0   1  01/01/2019          A
1   1  04/01/2019          B <-difference 3 days
2   2  02/01/2019          A
3   3  02/01/2019          A

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

s =  df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff()
df = df[(s.isnull() | (s > pd.Timedelta(2, 'd')))]
print (df)
   ID       Date Event_Type
0   1 2019-01-01          A
1   1 2019-01-04          B
2   2 2019-01-02          A
3   3 2019-01-02          A
```